# Task Bar Randomly Disappears On Reboot (Resolved)

Tags: settings, dual-boot

Randomly, if I boot my system, on the login screen the task bar will be gone. When I get pasted the login screen the taskbar is still gone. The only way I can reboot is by holding down my power button since I can't get to the power button icon in the top right. sudo reboot just hangs. Not sure what is causing it. The next boot I do everything is fine. Anyone else experience this?

Desktop
7th Gen Intel i5
16GB Ram
GTX 1080
Dual booting with Windows 10, but Windows and eOS are completely on different drives.

UPDATE/RESOLVED: This only happens when I choose restart from Windows and choose eOS from the boot manager. Its like the hardware is still in control by Windows. Fresh reboot seems to allow eOS to see the hardware and shows the toolbar. This is my working theory, but I now know how to avoid this issue.

Comment: I do not know if it is the case in your situatuion but restarting from Windows has some problems, like my laptop speakers do not work but headphone port works. 

Can you move the update you did into an answer of your question and later set it the correct one in order to make the question above resolved in the StackExcahnge system?

Comment: Yeah for sure. Figures Windows would do that to you lol. Thanks, Bo. I'll make it resolved properly here in a few hours when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE/RESOLVED: This only happens when I choose restart from Windows and choose eOS from the boot manager. Its like the hardware is still in control by Windows. Fresh reboot seems to allow eOS to see the hardware and shows the toolbar. This is my working theory, but I now know how to avoid this issue.

Comment: Please mark this answer of you like the correct one when it is possible, in order your question to be marked as resolved into StackExchange sysyem.